# How can I make Typescript correctly infer a type in a switch case?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, type-inference

I have the following EmailType and function, and typescript currently complains about "*thread is possibly undefined*", although it shouldn't.

How can i make typescript correctly infer the `thread` property type inside the respective case block?

```js
type SentEmail = {
  recipients: {
    main: string[],
    cc: string[]
  }
  // ...Other props, not relevant for this example
};
type EmailType = 'new' | 'reply' | 'replyAll' | 'forward';

const computeInitialSenderEmail = <Type extends EmailType>(
    senderEmails: string[],
    type: Type,
    thread: Type extends 'new' ? undefined : SentEmail
): string => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'reply':
        case 'replyAll':
        case 'forward':
            return (
                thread.recipients.main.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ?? // <------
                thread.recipients.cc.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ?? // <------
                senderEmails[0]
            );
        default:
            return senderEmails[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] we can just paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without having unrelated issues.  Surely `const EmailType = 'new' | 'reply' | 'replyAll' | 'forward';` is not what you wanted to write, and there are other undeclared things in there.  It will help us get to work on your issue.

Comment: Once you do that: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkaKpN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I added more information to my answer, thanks for replying. Feel free to write that up as an answer, that worked and satisfied my needs, thanks!

Comment: I've [edit]ed the question code to use `type` instead of `const`, since those are types and not values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's support for [narrowing via control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (such as your `switch`/`case` block) doesn't currently apply to [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters. So while checking `type` will have an effect on the type of `type`, it has no effect whatsoever on `Type`. And therefore it has no effect on `thread`.  There are various open issues asking for some improvement here, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), but for now it's not part of the language.  So if you want to use `switch`/`case` to relate `type` to `thread`, you can't use generics.

The supported way to do this is to switch from generics to a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Specifically, in your case, you can make the `type` and `thread` parameters into a [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a discriminated union of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  Like this:

```
const computeInitialSenderEmail = (
  senderEmails: string[],
  ...[type, thread]:
    ["new", undefined] |
    ['reply' | 'replyAll' | 'forward', SentEmail]
): string => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'reply':
    case 'replyAll':
    case 'forward':
      return (
        thread.recipients.main.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ??
        thread.recipients.cc.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ??
        senderEmails[0]
      );
    default:
      return senderEmails[0];
  }
};
```

That might look a little weird, but the idea is that `[type, thread]` is, when considered to be a single object, of a discriminated union type, where the first element is the discriminant, and determines the type of the second element.  And luckily TypeScript supports [destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions).  Otherwise we'd have needed to write something like

```
const computeInitialSenderEmail = (
  senderEmails: string[],
  ...rest:
    ["new", undefined] |
    ['reply' | 'replyAll' | 'forward', SentEmail]
): string => {
  switch (rest[0]) {
    case 'reply':
    case 'replyAll':
    case 'forward':
      return (
        rest[1].recipients.main.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ??
        rest[1].recipients.cc.find((r) => senderEmails.includes(r)) ??
        senderEmails[0]
      );
    default:
      return senderEmails[0];
  }
};
```

So that's the answer to your question as asked.  Note, you might even want to write

```
...[type, thread]: ["new"] | ['reply' | 'replyAll' | 'forward', SentEmail]
```

where you just accept `["new"]` instead of `["new", undefined]`, since presumably `computeInitialSenderEmail("new")` is more ergonomic than `computeInitialSenderEmail("new", undefined)`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoXAUQLZ2AG2QG8BYAKGWSggWAAdgMwBnALmPMst1HebCigA5gG0AugBpOXBAj4Dh46QF9yqsuQQB7EP2TbsdAK6QAkiGBhgcfOhAATaDjyEAvMgAU05hkdRnBGzI-IIgopLSAHTRImAAnnQQEshgABbUcPZirNKUIgBEIBAA7vnJRg4QMKAQWcgAPrnIIgDk1HT4cS0NyG0QHXEAgvj43fW9MFpQxXBQ9i3JdmAB+GLkAJTyoULIrgB8HBTBxZYIqZ7xieuHXPpwPr3tnS05R5QI9yh9A8Ojr7cfB4tSbTWbzf63KgQMBGKAgTxNW5pDL2SLUWgMJjMSI8ECRaoODweKDXfbBXxOHj4bGgBD4IyOZjE9bXAD8rMRXGREEyaJo9EY4GxsnxoHsRJJuwOPkq-ipNJAdIZECZJLZHLekJlfhWzBEAAY1prKOsANxNRzwIz4MAQ27UGFw8my3UGsTmo7qZQezQ6PQGYxmCxWGx2HVUgByWjAABEVQIjAhHbVdgijtrKS4giFFBEjtE+fw7c1CiUysgKpaanVGprWk8uj1vp1fmMJlMZnMFmgmCsjZtggowlKbsdTudifG3ddSJrAV8Gy8mvPHv0WyMl3PPu3QV3i5QHbD4V5jVxqPwRABGMR8jGClg4vB4gni5kjjNyrORWn0xnM9WcgeU7XreApYpEIovhKpLShSn6BN+iq-iq-7IOygHOuGWZupyZoWlUcDWranKHk6H6uoaHqUF6PoaHR2i6GA+haIYJgQOYljWLYcErAATKmJ6UOR8pbLmUj5jElxJCk6Q8lk7AFEUpRiD09Zro24zNkMG5NiCnbzIsvZUv2onDmSs5CScYBnBcCQQDOy7blpm4Ak5DatsWK7Ah2YIuZCpHHhh3K8uiYFCo+oCioSb5ksJX4-sqqosmhGqQlyskhfymLhZBYrQe+PHyohSp-mqKUYXFgQ4aeeGapahE2vuUKOvClXUm6VHIDR5BAA)

Comment: Very nicely explained, thanks again! +1